# Batch Class Question

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to do a mass update of all account email fields to "testing.com"
however I am getting an error message saying my variable does not exist. This is my class.

```
global class BatchUpdateAccountField implements Database.Batchable <SObject>{
    global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT name from Account');
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> acList)
    {
        for(Account ac :acList)
        {
            ac.email = ac.email + ' Testing.com';
        }
       
        update acList;
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        System.debug('>>>Finish');
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to access a value on an SObject record (as you're currently doing with the `Email` field), you need to query for it. Providing the exact error message (don't paraphrase it, you'll end up omitting the important parts) also helps.

Comment: Hey Derek, the error is on s.email = s.email + ' Testing.com';  Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: s at line 10 column 23

Comment: Is your loop variable in your actual code 's', or is it 'ac'? Also, like I said earlier, you need to query for a field if you want to use it in the right hand side of an expression.

Comment: In addition to Derek's point about the query, there is no `email` field on the Account object, see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm).  Did you create a custom field on Account to track email?  Please [edit] your post to include more details about your cnofiguration.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard field email on Account Object unless you are using a person account.

If  you are using person account then the field name is PersonEmail.

ac.PersonEmail = ac.PersonEmail + ' Testing.com';

If email is a custom field on your Account object then the api name will be of the form email__c

ac.Email__c = ac.Email__c + ' Testing.com';

The above will resolve the compile error but you will still get a runtime error if you do not include the field in SOQL query in start method.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line `return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT name from Account');` since you have not added your email field while doing the query.

Change the query as below.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT name, email from Account');
```